# Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of a ring $R$. Is $M[x]$ a maximal ideal of $R[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of a ring $R$. Prove that $M[x]$ is not a maximal ideal of $R[x]$

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take the quotient $R[X]/M[X]$, use your previous question. Is the quotient a field? What does that tell you?

Comment: @BenWest : you have given sufficient hint :) this should not take much time for him to confirm...

Comment: I know that $R/M$ is a field. But what should we do then?

Comment: You already know $R[x]/M[x]\cong (R/M)[x]$ is a polynomial ring in which $x$ has no inverse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M[X]$ is not  maximum, because if it is  $(R/M)[X]$ is a field (in view the isomorphisme $(R/M)[X]\cong R[X]/M[X]$), absurd!

**edit** $(R/M)[X]$ is never a ﬁeld (for example, $X\neq 0$ is never a unit in $(R/M)[X]$)

Comment: Can you explain more precise?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 see the change

Comment: Why $(R/M)[X]$ is never a field?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 $X\in (R/M)[X] $  and $X\neq 0$ but $X$ does not admit an inverse in $(R/M)[X] $

Comment: Ehm, of course. Thank you so much